# Double method in C#

Tags: c#

Within this extract,

```
class Program
{
    static double xarisxi(double[] parsedMasiv)
    {
        double [] returnedMmasiv = new double[parsedMasiv.Length];
        int k = 0;
        while (k < returnedMmasiv.Length)
        {
            returnedMmasiv[k] = Math.Pow(parsedMasiv[k], k);
            Console.WriteLine(returnedMmasiv[k]);
            k++;
        }
        return returnedMmasiv;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] userMasiv = new double[5];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < userMasiv.Length)
        {
            userMasiv[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            i++;
        }
        xarisxi(userMasiv);
    }
}
```

the line `return returnedMmasiv;` is raising an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'double'

What is wrong?

Comment: It *may* be that you need to change the return type, as BackDoorNoBaby suggests - or you may need something else entirely. It's unclear since at the moment you *ignore* any return value from `xarisxi` - we don't know what further work you may have been intending to do from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your function signature to return a `double[]` not `double`

```
static double[] xarisxi(double[] parsedMasiv)
{
    double [] returnedMmasiv = new double[parsedMasiv.Length];
    int k = 0;
    while (k < returnedMmasiv.Length)
    {
        returnedMmasiv[k] = Math.Pow(parsedMasiv[k], k);
        Console.WriteLine(returnedMmasiv[k]);
        k++;
    }
    return returnedMmasiv;
}
```